# How to assure messages are processed and persisted in the correct order?

Tags: microservices, message-queue

If I have a message queue that receives scoring messages for a sports match for each change in the match score and a multi-instance service responsible for reading said queue, processing scores, and persisting them. How can I assure messages are processed in the right order but still have the advantage of multiple instances for fast processing?

I.e.:

```
message_1 = Team A 1x2 Team B
message_2 = Team A 2x2 Team B
```

Messages must be processed and persisted in order or else the final score on the database could be `Team A 1x2 Team B`, which is not the correct final score.

Comment: It depends on the queue.  For example, in Kafka, if you partition your queue such that all the messages for the Team A vs. Team B match are in the same partition, the standard consumer group coordination will ensure that at most one instance is consuming that partition.

Comment: I use AWS SQS, and I am afraid I don't have much control over the queue itself. I will need some logic on that on the service or the database, maybe both. I was wondering if distributed lock was a good idea, but then I would need a distributed lock for each match, not sure if that is feasible.